# Need to format(Indent) invalid JSON String in Javascript. (Best Reference: JSONLINT)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Conside I have a JSON like this(Example: `{ "abcd":"abcd" )`.
I forgot to add braces at the end and its in minified format. I need to convert this into beautify JSON even its invalid using JavaScript like mentioned below

```
{
  \n\t "abcd":"abcd"
```

Is there any solutions in JavaScript or TypeScript

Actual:

```
{ "abcd": "abcd","decs": { "jan": 1, "feb" :2 }
```

Expected:

```
{
   \n\t "abcd": "abcd", 
   \n\t "decs": 
         \n {
           \n\t\t "jan":1,
           \n\t\t "feb":2 
           \n\t }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your JSON is stored in a variable.

```
let json = '{ "abcd": "abcd","decs": { "jan": 1, "feb" :2 }';
```

> *If you don't know what let is, use var.*

Then you can do:

```
json += '}';
```

And to verify it:

```
console.log( JSON.parse(json) );
```

Comment: Logic should be applicable for Dynamic JSON. and it should indent if JSON is invalid. user can miss any parenthesis (i.e Invalid JSON). I need to indent each and every line so that user can able to check if any parenthesis is missing